# Error en condicional en foreach usando ASP.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2015

Compañeros de Stack Overflow en español, tengo el siguiente error al realizar esta condicional `ViewBag.p.Where(n => n.Lider == namelider` en el ciclo `foreach`.

Aquí les muestro parte de mi código:

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    @foreach (var item in ViewBag.c)
    {
        var namelider = item.lider;
        <tr>
            <td>@item.nombres</td>
            <td>@item.lider</td>
            <td>@item.eje_funcional</td>
            @foreach(var peso in ViewBag.p.Where(n => n.Lider == namelider))
            {
                <td>@peso.Lider</td>
            }
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

El error que me aparece es el siguiente:

> No se puede usar una expresión lambda como argumento de una
>   operación enviada de forma dinámica sin convertirla antes en un tipo delegado
>   o de árbol de expresión.

Agrego consultas del controlador:

```
ViewBag.c = (from p in db.Collaborators
             where p.grupo_lider == "NO"
             select p).ToList();

ViewBag.p = (from p in db.Objectives
             select p).ToList();

ViewBag.cal = (from p in db.CalificarColaboradors
               select p).ToList();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lo que sucede es que `ViewBag` es un objeto dinámico (`dynamic`) que no hereda propiedades ni métodos del objeto que utilizas originalmente, necesitas hacer un `cast` *explícito* al tipo de objeto original. Esto es llamado [unboxing](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/2225/boxing-and-unboxing-in-c) y es bastante sencillo:

```
@foreach(var peso in ((List<SI_OldMutual.Models.Objectives>)ViewBag.p).Where(n => n.Lider == namelider))
{
    <td>@peso.Lider</td>
}
```

Comment: Tiempo sin verte activo Kroneaux, espero estes bien... Muchas gracias por tu respuesta sin embargo en TuClase no se que poner, teniendo en cuenta que en la vista en la primera linea dice @model List<SI_OldMutual.Models.CalificarColaborador>

Comment: Gracias, espero que te esté yendo bien, veo que sigues preguntando sobre MVC así que creo vas por buen camino! Para saber exactamente qué poner, yo recurriría al IntelliSense de Visual Studio. En el controlador coloca algo como `var _p = (from p in db.Objectives ...` y pasa el cursor encima de `_p` para ver qué te indica.

Comment: dice (variable local)List<Objectives> _P

Comment: ¿`Objectives` en qué espacio de nombres está?

Comment: namespace SI_OldMutual.Models

Comment: Debes hacer *cast* a `List<SI_OldMutual.Models.Objectives >`. Actualicé la respuesta, revisa si así funciona.

Comment: jeje ya antes lo habia intentado bro y funciono, muchas gracias

Comment: ¡Me alegra que lo hiciera! Y ya me verás más seguido por aquí, jeje.

Comment: +1 compañero! Explica bien la respuesta yo di casi solo codigo, saludos!

Answer (score 3):

Lo que podrías hacer es trabajar como un `IEnumerable` el valor de tu `ViewBag.p` a una lista del tipo del objeto que tienes almacenado:

```
 @foreach(var peso in ((IEnumerable<Objectives>)ViewBag.p).Where(n => n.Lider == namelider))
 {
     <td>@peso.Lider</td>
 }
```

Comment: No entiendo muy bien, en este caso mi objeto viene siendo Lider? o a que te refieres amigo, si me puedes explicar por favor

Comment: Tu tienes desde el controlador alguna lista que almecenas en `Viewbag.p` verdad? para poder recorrerla, podrias hacer que trabaje como un `IEnumerable`

Comment: Hola, amigo edite mi pregunta y subi las consultas, pasa que soy nuevo en c# y no entiendo muy bien lo de objetos

Comment: ahi actualice @ByGroxD

Comment: en Objectives dice que no se encontro que falta algun using o una referencia de ensamblado

Comment: que modelo tienes en la vista?

Comment: En la parte superior de la vista esta esto de la siguiente manera @model List<SI_OldMutual.Models.CalificarColaborador>